# GIT Repository: "invalid author/committer line - missing space before date"

Tags: git

When trying to make a move to github from bitbucket I've encountered fatal error in one of commits:

```
error in commit d8b1774aa7bd98c6494a1e31acef943d0e0cbf03: missingSpaceBeforeDate: invalid author/committer line - missing space before date
```

`cat-file` shows:

```
author john <john@doe.com>removed backup files. Modified  <> 1397201439 +0200
committer john <john@doe.com> 1397201439 +0200
```

How can I amend this commit and add missing space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved the issue with:

```
git filter-branch --env-filter \
'if [ $GIT_COMMIT = d8b1774aa7bd98c6494a1e31acef943d0e0cbf03 ]
 then
     export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="John"
     export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="Fri, 11 Apr 2014 07:30:39 +0000"
     export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="Fri, 11 Apr 2014 07:30:39 +0000"
     export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="john.doe@blah.com"
 fi' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error. Solved it by deleting the tags associated with the problematic commits (did not need the tags anyway) and then mirroring the repo.

`git tag -d TAGNAME`

I was able to list the problematic commits with the following command:

`git fsck`